# Producing JSON Arrays for Multiple Elements with same model name

Tags: angularjs

I am generating json data for multiple elements with angular. I am getting output as

```
{"field":{"name":{"0":"a","1":"b"},"length":{"0":10,"1":20}}}
```

I want jsondata to be sophisticated (in array form) such as:

```
{"field":[{"name":"a", "length":10},{"name":"b", "length":20}]}
```

How can I achieve this ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />  
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="JsonController as ctrl">

   <div ng-repeat="a in [1,2] track by $index">
     <input type="text" ng-model="task.field['name'][$index]">
     <input type="number" ng-model="task.field['length'][$index]"> 
   </div>

    <pre>
    {{task}}
    </pre>
  </div>

<script>
  (function() {
    angular.module("mainApp", []).controller("JsonController", function($scope) {
          $scope.task = {};

          });
    }());
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="a in [1,2] track by $index">
  <input type="text" ng-model="task.field[$index].name">
  <input type="number" ng-model="task.field[$index].length"> 
</div>

$scope.task = {
    field: []
};
```

Although I don't like this approach at all. Why don't you create your objects upfront in the controller, and just iterate over them:

```
<div ng-repeat="t in task.field">
  <input type="text" ng-model="t.name">
  <input type="number" ng-model="t.length"> 
</div>

$scope.task = {
    field: [{}, {}]
};
```

Comment: actually my example is minified version taken from some module just to illustrate.

Comment: Please correct in your first block $scope.task = { field: []};